# Counting or Radix sort which is preferred in terms of time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, radix-sort, counting-sort

I'm given with an array of integers from the set {0,1,…,n} wherein I need to sort the array in time O(n). But I'm not sure whether to do Radix /Counting sort for this problem.  Can anyone give your suggestions on this?

Comment: Do you remember what was in school? Associative algorithms cannot be faster than O(n . log2 n), so if you need O(n) then quicksort is immediately out of game.

Comment: @AlKepp: I think you mean *comparison sort* algorithms. I'm not sure what an "associative algorithm" is, in this context (it's often used in [a completely different context](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ1113395)) but I would guess that it means "sorting using an associative mapping", which of course could be O(n).

Comment: @rici yes I meant sorting with comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort in `O(n)` time, then [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is the only option. It has `Θ(n)` time and `Θ(n)` space complexity.

[Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) requires `O(n log(n))` time in the worst case (since length of the key in your case is `log(n)`), and [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is `O(n log(n))` in average case and can be `O(n²)` in the worst case, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Cheers.. that helped!!

Answer (score 0):

If n is small enough that an array of n elements will fit in memory, then a counting sort would be fastest.

For larger n, a radix sort is needed. If the keys are stored in 32 bit or 64 bit integers, then a base 256 radix sort will take 4 passes for 32 bits, 8 passes for 64 bits. Since time complexity ignores constants, then such a radix sort technically has time complexity O(n). However, if the radix sort uses the maximum key value to reduce the number of passes, then time complexity would be O(n log(n)) (actual complexity would be n ceil(log256(n))).